# spring boot actuator refreshscope

Tags: java, spring-boot-actuator

I have an application which is running on multiple AWS hosts behind a load balancer. All of these instances load the configuration from a spring config server. I can use spring boot admin server to identify the the URL's so that I can execute the POST at hostname:port/actuator/refresh command for individual host using POSTMAN. As the number of hosts increase, it becomes difficult to run a command for each one of the hosts. Is there a way I can do the same with a single command?

Comment: you must have the servers poll for a signal to update.

Comment: Are you using an API Gateway?

Comment: It is a spring cloud application deployed in mesosphere/DCOS. I am building the spring boot admin for service discovery and cloud config refresh functionality.

Answer (score 1):

We use something similar for our application
i.e Spring applications fetching properties from config server and a spring boot admin server to which all these application registers.

We have exposed an post api in bootadmin which calls refresh endpoint on all instances of specified app.
Since bootadmin has all information about registered apps, we are using it to 'publish' message to all 'subscribed' apps.